# Twitter Bootstrap Popover: how to set "placement" depending on screen size?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers. On larger screens, I want the popover to appear on the right. On smaller screens, I think I want it to appear either at the top or bottom. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most people use CSS media queries for responsive designs, we can do the exact same thing in javascript.

```
//detect devicen width
if(screen.width < somevalue){

}else if(screen.width > somevalue){

}
```

Would be the same as the media query equivalent of `device-width`

Or, if you preferred to use the visible width

```
//detect visible width
if(document.documentElement.clientWidth < somevalue){

}else if(document.documentElement.clientWidth > somevalue){

}
```

This will be consistent across all browsers and devices with media-queries.

Answer (score 7):

I put responsive placement attributes on my elements, such as `data-placement-xs="top" data-placement-md="left"` and use the following piece of JavaScript to initialize my tooltips in all of the pages:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
    'placement': function(tt, trigger) {
        var $trigger = $(trigger);
        var windowWidth = $(window).width();

        var xs = $trigger.attr('data-placement-xs');
        var sm = $trigger.attr('data-placement-sm');
        var md = $trigger.attr('data-placement-md');
        var lg = $trigger.attr('data-placement-lg');
        var general = $trigger.attr('data-placement');

        return (windowWidth >= 1200 ? lg : undefined) ||
            (windowWidth >= 992 ? md : undefined) ||
            (windowWidth >= 768 ? sm : undefined) ||
            xs ||
            general ||
            "top";
    }
});
```

Comment: A very elegant solution to a problem that few people seem to think about. +1 from me.

Comment: I think these data-attributes should be implemented into the popover and tooltip plugin by default! This solution works great for me.