# Change tooltip position with CSS depending on screen size

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can do it with JS like this:

```
$(function(){
    if($(document).width < 768){
        $("#myDiv").tooltip({'placement':'left'});
    }else{
        $("#myDiv").tooltip({'placement':'top'});
    }
});
```

But I would prefer solution that responds when the screen size is changed. Is there any way to do this, or should I settle for the above?

Comment: @Blazemonger Sorry for the confusing wording. I'd still be using `$("#myDiv").tooltip();` to initiate the tooltip. I just want the position to dynamically change based on the screen width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `window.onresize` event:

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    var pos = ($(window).width() < 768) ? 'left' : 'top';
    $("#myDiv").tooltip({'placement': pos});
}).trigger('resize');
```

Answer (score 0):

See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27344574/187996

In short, I define responsive-aware attributes for placement of the tooltip (such as `data-placement-xs="top" data-placement-md="left"`), and then use a custom JavaScript code to identify the placement each time the tooltip is shown.